# Simple Html/JavaScript question regarding equations and conditionals

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to programming/coding so this is probably quite easy for most of you. 
I am supposed to create a web app for weight conversion: from U.S. Dollars to Japanese Yen and from Japanese
Yen to U.S. Dollars. Assume 1 Dollar = 112.57 Yen
- Use one input box
- Use a drop-down to select which conversion to perform
- The two formulas are: Yen =Dollars*112.57 AND Dollars=Yen/112.57

This is what I got so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function convert()
{
var Dollars, Yen; //declare variables

//INPUT
if (inCurrency.value == "U.S Dollars to Yen") {x.value=Dollars}
else if (inCurrency.value == "Yen to U.S Dollars") {x.value=Yen}

//PROCESSING
Yen = Dollars * 112.57;
Dollars = Yen / 112.57;

//OUTPUT
spYen.innerHTML = Yen;
spDollars.innerHTML = Dollars;

}
</script>
<style>
.CCC {
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 12pt;
color: lightseagreen;
}

.DDD {
font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
font-size: 12pt;
color: lawngreen;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Currency Converter</h2>
<span class="CCC">Select one:</span>

<select id="inCurrency">
<option>U.S Dollars to Yen</option>
<option>Yen to U.S Dollars</option>

</select><br />
<span style="color:deeppink">Enter amount </span><span id="x"></span><input 
type="text" /><br />

<i>
<span class="DDD">Dollars: </span><span id="spDollars"></span><br />
<span class="DDD">Yen: </span><span id="spYen"></span><br />

</i>

<input type="button" value="Convert Currency" onClick="convert()" />
<br />
<br />
<a href="Index.html">Home

</body>
</html>
```

[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEDJl.png) the problem I am having is the actual coding in the head section. I am not sure how to set it up right so does it executes the equations. I was wondering if someone could help. Thank you.

Comment: in ur provided link nothing is working. but when i run it from my local it gives NAN in result ?
what is ur actual problem or where u get stuck ..can u be more specific ?

Comment: `if (inCurrency.value == "U.S Dollars to Yen") {x.value=Dollars}` ... why are you setting `x.value` to `undefined` (as it would be in either case in that first if/then), and a `span` doesn't have a meaningful `value` property - `Yen = Dollars * 112.57;
Dollars = Yen / 112.57;` both Yen and Dollars are declared with no initial value, therefore undefined ... so any Math on then will result in `NaN` - what is `spYen` and `spDollars` .... don't rely on an id of an element being "automagically" available as a global variable - it wont always work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way of getting your desired result.
I have fixed the HTML and Javascript for you.

Directly trying to get/set the id values is not the right way.

```js
function convert()
{
var Dollars, Yen; //declare variables

//INPUT
var e = document.getElementById("inCurrency");
var inCurrency = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

var amount = document.getElementById("x").value;

//PROCESSING
if (inCurrency == "U.S Dollars to Yen")
{
  Dollars = amount;
  Yen = Dollars * 112.57;
}
else if (inCurrency == "Yen to U.S Dollars")
{
  Yen = amount;
  Dollars = Yen / 112.57;
}

//OUTPUT
document.getElementById("spYen").innerHTML = Yen;
document.getElementById("spDollars").innerHTML = Dollars;

}
```

```css
.CCC {
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 12pt;
color: lightseagreen;
}

.DDD {
font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
font-size: 12pt;
color: lawngreen;
}
```

```html
<h2>Currency Converter</h2>
<span class="CCC">Select one:</span>

<select id="inCurrency">
<option>U.S Dollars to Yen</option>
<option>Yen to U.S Dollars</option>

</select><br />
<span style="color:deeppink">Enter amount </span><input id="x" type="text" /><br />

<i>
<span class="DDD">Dollars: </span><span id="spDollars"></span><br />
<span class="DDD">Yen: </span><span id="spYen"></span><br />

</i>

<input type="button" value="Convert Currency" onClick="convert()" />
<br />
<br />
<a href="Index.html">Home
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function convert()
{
   convertRule = document.querySelector("#inCurrency").value;
   amount = document.querySelector("#amount").value;
   if (inCurrency.value == "U.S Dollars to Yen"){
      Yen = amount * 112.57;
      document.getElementById("spDollars").innerHTML = Yen
   }else{
      Dollars = amount * 122.22;
      document.getElementById("spDollars").innerHTML = Dollars
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain how this answers the question?

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Good answers help the OP and future readers understand why the code in question didn't work as well as an example of what could work instead.

Comment: thanks @stealththeninja for your explanation. actually i was at office in the mean time i just post the reply that is why i not able to give the proper description about answer.